# image in twitter bootstrap navbar in mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

How can I insert logo image in the navbar of Twitter Bootstrap?

Main requirements:

The image needs to be placed on left.

Brand class to be next to it. I tried it by shifting the brand to right. The image is seen, but on mobile or small browser window, the brand class comes on top of the image.

The drop-down menu on the far right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap your image inside a div and add the `.brand` class to it as well, so it should look something like this:

```
<div class="brand"><img class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<a href="#" class="brand">Project name</a>
```

Or better yet, if you want your logo to be clickable just insert it inside the `a` brand link, like so:

```
<a href="#" class="brand"><img class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/50x50"> Project name</a>
```

Comment: I am using:
<a class="brand" href="#" <img alt="" src="../images/30x30.png" style="height:114px">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a>
works on normal windows. href text overlaps the logo in smaller, half length, windows.

Comment: @Gattoo instead of none-breaking spaces include the image inside a span tag and add some padding-right to it.

Comment: This worked:<a class="brand" href="#"> <img src="images/30x30.png" style="padding-right:50px">Home</a>. Thanks.

Comment: @Gattoo wouldnt this affect the page on small devices like mobile or tablet size???